# Wildfly custom JAAS LoginModule with custom Principal in RunAs and unauthenticated

Tags: jboss7.x, jaas, wildfly-10, principal

I'm looking for help with custom Principal used in custom LoginModule on Wildfly10/Jboss 7.
I would like to put some additional data into my custom principal connected with authorization as well as audit data such as sessionId gathered from HttpRequest in my custom LoginModule.
In EJB implementation i'm getting my custom principal object from sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal() and it works pretty well when user is authenticated by my LoginModule (where i produce desired principal object).

Problem starts when i turn off BASIC authentication on any webservice or when i'm using @RunAs implementation in my EJB call stack.
In case with authentication turned off im getting "anonymous" SimlePrincipal object from getCallerPrincipal() and SimplePrincipal with one role in case with @RunAs. 
Is there any way to force Jboss to use my custom LoginModule or any other module
where i can produce my custom principal and put in into sessionContextCaller principal?

Comment: If you use JASPIC (WildFly supports it really well) you can use your own custom principal.

Comment: Thanks. JASPIC seems to be much more handy for my case. But I still don't know how to intercept JBoss @RunAs implementation in Jaspic. It is possible at all?